# A given column is not a column of the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, function, pipeline, transformer-model

**Hi everyone!**

I have a test `DataFrame` to find out how `FunctionTransformer` works in a `Pipeline`.
I created a function that drops one column.
I transform it with `FunctionTransformer` and put the result into `ColumnTransformer` constructor and got the error.
The function I created doesn't take any arguments, hence I don't need to call it with some certain values.
But in `ColumnTransformer` I have to specify the columns.

In the second try I put my `FunctionTransformer` result into the final `Pipeline` instead of `ColumnTransformer` and get the same error.

In addition to that, could someone please explain how data flow in `FunctionTransformer`, `ColumnTransformer` and `Pipeline`?

Why does someone use `fit_transform` in `ColumnTransformer`?
Isn't it the same as `Pipeline.fit`? What's the difference?

In what order should I create columns and `DataFrame`s for a `Pipeline` chain?

First, I define my function.
Then split data for `x` and `y`, with `x` data into numerical and categorical columns.
I'd like the `Pipeline` and `ColumnTransformer` to use the function and transform my data.

I don't know how data is being sent inside the `Pipeline` and `ColumnTransformer`.
I define `x` and `y` before the `Pipeline`, but inside `Pipeline` it transforms in some different way.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

a = range(1, 10)
b = range(10, 100, 10)
c = range(11, 110, 11)
d = range(12, 120, 12)

e = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg','hh','ii']
f = ['ф','и','с','в','у','а','п','р','ш']
g = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(']

test={'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d, 'e': e, 'f': f, 'g': g}

data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
print(data)
```

```py
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g
0   1   10  11  12  aa  ф   !
1   2   20  22  24  bb  и   @
2   3   30  33  36  cc  с   #
3   4   40  44  48  dd  в   $
4   5   50  55  60  ee  у   %
5   6   60  66  72  ff  а   ^
6   7   70  77  84  gg  п   &
7   8   80  88  96  hh  р   *
8   9   90  99  108 ii  ш   (
```

```py
def drop_cols(value):
  cols = ['g']
  return data.drop(cols, axis=1)

bad_cols = Pipeline([('bad', FunctionTransformer(drop_cols))])
x = data.drop('f', axis=1)
y = data.f
num_clmns = data.select_dtypes(include='int').columns
cat_clmns = data.select_dtypes(include='object').columns

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=0.3, random_state=42)

trans = ColumnTransformer([
    ('bad_cols', bad_cols, data.columns),
    ('num_trans1', StandardScaler(), num_clmns),
    ('cat_trans1', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_clmns)

    ], remainder='passthrough')

pipe = Pipeline([('trans', trans), ('rtc', RandomForestClassifier())])

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Same error if I put `bad_cols` into the final `Pipeline` instead of `ColumnTransformer`:

```py
trans = ColumnTransformer([
    ('num_trans1', StandardScaler(), num_clmns),
    ('cat_trans1', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_clmns)

    ], remainder='passthrough')

pipe = Pipeline([('bad_cols', bad_cols), ('trans', trans), ('rtc', RandomForestClassifier())])

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:

12 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'f'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
KeyError: 'f'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in _get_column_indices(X, key)
    454 
    455         except KeyError as e:
--> 456             raise ValueError("A given column is not a column of the dataframe") from e
    457 
    458         return column_indices

ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Use a `FunctionTransformer` to apply custom transformations to your data. Estimators used in the `ColumnTransformer` are applied to the `X` data separately. Dropping features can be handled with the `remainder` parameter in `ColumnTransformer`. `Pipeline` applies the estimators listed in `steps` in sequential order -- the output of one is the input to the next.

```py
import pandas as pd  # 2.1.4
# import sklearn  # 1.3.2
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler


# Original data.
a = range(1, 10)
b = range(10, 100, 10)
c = range(11, 110, 11)
d = range(12, 120, 12)
e = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii']
f = ['ф', 'и', 'с', 'в', 'у', 'а', 'п', 'р', 'ш']
g = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(']
test = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d, 'e': e, 'f': f, 'g': g}
data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

X = data.drop(columns="f")
y = data.f
num_clmns = X.select_dtypes(include='int').columns
cat_clmns = X.select_dtypes(include='object').columns

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.3, random_state=42)

trans = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num_trans1', StandardScaler(), num_clmns),
        ('cat_trans1', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_clmns),
    ],
    remainder="drop",
)

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('trans', trans), ('rtc', RandomForestClassifier())])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

---

## The Problem

From your question:

> ... and put the result into `ColumnTransformer` constructor and got the error.... But in `ColumnTransformer` I have to specify the columns.

If I use your original `drop_cols` function and code:

```py
import pandas as pd  # 2.1.4
# import sklearn  # 1.3.2
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler


# Original function.
def drop_cols(value):
    cols = ['g']
    return data.drop(cols, axis=1)


# Original data.
a = range(1, 10)
b = range(10, 100, 10)
c = range(11, 110, 11)
d = range(12, 120, 12)
e = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii']
f = ['ф', 'и', 'с', 'в', 'у', 'а', 'п', 'р', 'ш']
g = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(']
test = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d, 'e': e, 'f': f, 'g': g}
data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

bad_cols = Pipeline([('bad', FunctionTransformer(drop_cols))])
x = data.drop('f', axis=1)
y = data.f
num_clmns = data.select_dtypes(include='int').columns
cat_clmns = data.select_dtypes(include='object').columns

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=0.3, random_state=42)

trans = ColumnTransformer([
    ('bad_cols', bad_cols, data.columns),
    ('num_trans1', StandardScaler(), num_clmns),
    ('cat_trans1', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_clmns)

    ], remainder='passthrough')

pipe = Pipeline([('trans', trans), ('rtc', RandomForestClassifier())])

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

We do indeed raise a `ValueError`:

```py
ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe
```

This appears to be related to a `KeyError`:

```py
KeyError: 'f'
```

A little digging reveals that `"f"` is a column in `data`, but not in `x` as it is dropped right after `bad_cols` is defined:

```py
bad_cols = Pipeline([('bad', FunctionTransformer(drop_cols))])
x = data.drop('f', axis=1)  # <-- here
y = data.f
```

Then `cat_clmns` is defined using `data` instead of `x`:

```py
num_clmns = data.select_dtypes(include='int').columns
cat_clmns = data.select_dtypes(include='object').columns  # <-- here
```

A few lines later, `cat_clmns` is supplied to `ColumnTransformer` as an argument for `cat_trans1`:

```py
trans = ColumnTransformer([
    ('bad_cols', bad_cols, data.columns),
    ('num_trans1', StandardScaler(), num_clmns),
    ('cat_trans1', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_clmns)  # <-- here

    ], remainder='passthrough')
```

Because the `pipe` is being fit on `X_train` and `y_train`, the pipeline tries to execute the `cat_trans1` using features in `cat_clmns`, but `"f"` (present in `cat_clmns`) is not present in `X_train` at this point. This raises the `KeyError`.

---

## Getting To A Solution

To start, we should replace `data` with `x` when defining `num_clmns` and `cat_clmns` as `x` is a subset of `data`.

```py
bad_cols = Pipeline([('bad', FunctionTransformer(drop_cols))])
x = data.drop('f', axis=1)
y = data.f
num_clmns = x.select_dtypes(include='int').columns  # <-- here
cat_clmns = x.select_dtypes(include='object').columns  # <-- and here
```

After that you might think that replacing `data.columns` with `x.columns` in the `bad_cols` part of `ColumnTransformer` would fix everything.

```py
trans = ColumnTransformer([
    ('bad_cols', bad_cols, x.columns),  # <-- here
    ('num_trans1', StandardScaler(), num_clmns),
    ('cat_trans1', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_clmns)

    ], remainder='passthrough')
```

But this will result in a new error:

```py
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 9 and the array at index 1 has size 2.
```

This isn't so straightforward to debug. If you dig through your code, you'll notice that the dimensions of your original `data` are `(9, 7)` while the dimensions for `X_train` are `(2, 7)`. This is from your `train_test_split` arguments:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

Per the `train_test_split` source code [[1]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/3f89022fa04d293152f1d32fbc2a5bdaaf2df364/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2550) -> [[2]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/3f89022fa04d293152f1d32fbc2a5bdaaf2df364/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2649) -> [[3]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/3f89022fa04d293152f1d32fbc2a5bdaaf2df364/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2233) -> [[4]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/3f89022fa04d293152f1d32fbc2a5bdaaf2df364/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2285):

```py
from math import floor


train_size = 0.3  # defined in `train_test_split` args
n_samples = 9  # number of rows in `x`, supplied to `train_test_split`

floor(train_size * n_samples)  # --> 2
```

Because the `drop_cols` function returns a modified version of the original `data` instead of modifying an input (such as `x` or `X_train` seen during `fit`), the `ColumnTransformer` can't correctly concatenate the output of the three transformers along the 0th axis. To fix this we can refactor the `drop_cols` function to use its input:

```py
# Note the parameter name change.
def drop_cols(X: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    cols = ['g']
    return X.drop(cols, axis=1)  # <- Using input arg here.
```

Running with our changes we're now greeted with a new `ValueError`:

```py
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'dd'
```

This (again) comes from the `drop_cols` function -- the function returns the input (in this case `X_train`) without the column `"g"`. Take note that we are handling other columns via the `num_trans1` and `cat_trans1` transformers. Since `"dd"` is a member of column `e`, we know it will be handled by the `cat_trans1` transformer. Therefore we can drop it in the `drop_cols` function.

```py
def drop_cols(X: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    cols = ["e", 'g']  # <- added "e"
    return X.drop(cols, axis=1)
```

Now the code runs.

---

## Some Details and Suggestions

### `FunctionTransformer`

From your question:

> I created a function that drops one column. I transform it with `FunctionTransformer`... The function I created doesn't take any arguments, hence I don't need to call it with some certain values....

Per the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html):

> ... A FunctionTransformer forwards its X (and optionally y) arguments to a user-defined function or function object and returns the result of this function....

Docs for the `func` parameter:

> **func : *callable, default=None***
> The callable to use for the transformation. This will be passed the same arguments as transform, with args and kwargs forwarded. If func is None, then func will be the identity function.

This means that the function supplied to the `FunctionTransformer` must take ***at least one*** argument, specifically the `X` that will be passed to the `transform` method.

In your `drop_cols` function you have one required argument, `value`, but it isn't used when the function is called. If you want to use the `drop_cols` function appropriately (and ***not*** modify a global variable, i.e. `data`), I suggest modifying it so the required argument is used:

```py
# Suggested.
# NOTE -- I changed the name of the parameter from `value` to `data`.
def drop_cols(X: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  cols = ['g']
  return X.drop(cols, axis=1)
```

Wrapping the `drop_cols` function in a `FunctionTransformer` grants us access to the [`fit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.fit) and [`transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.transform) methods, among other attributes.

```py
import pandas as pd  # 2.1.4
# import sklearn  # 1.3.2
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer


def drop_cols(X: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    cols = ['g']
    return X.drop(cols, axis=1)


# Original data.
a = range(1, 10)
b = range(10, 100, 10)
c = range(11, 110, 11)
d = range(12, 120, 12)
e = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii']
f = ['ф', 'и', 'с', 'в', 'у', 'а', 'п', 'р', 'ш']
g = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(']
test = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d, 'e': e, 'f': f, 'g': g}
data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

# Wrapping `drop_cols` with `FunctionTransformer`.
drop_cols_trf = FunctionTransformer(func=drop_cols)

# Testing `fit_transform` on `data`.
out = drop_cols_trf.fit_transform(X=data)
print(out)
```

Notice that column `"g"` has been dropped.

```py
   a   b   c    d   e  f
0  1  10  11   12  aa  ф
1  2  20  22   24  bb  и
2  3  30  33   36  cc  с
3  4  40  44   48  dd  в
4  5  50  55   60  ee  у
5  6  60  66   72  ff  а
6  7  70  77   84  gg  п
7  8  80  88   96  hh  р
8  9  90  99  108  ii  ш
```

While this works, it isn't the best use of a `FunctionTransformer`. Perhaps a better approach would be to use a `ColumnTransformer` to handle the columns that are kept or dropped.

### `ColumnTransformer`

Per the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html):

> Applies transformers to columns of an array or pandas DataFrame.
>
> This estimator allows different columns or column subsets of the input to be transformed separately and the features generated by each transformer will be concatenated to form a single feature space. This is useful for heterogeneous or columnar data, to combine several feature extraction mechanisms or transformations into a single transformer.

We can combine this with a generic `FunctionTransformer` to control which features are passed along vs dropped. Note that the `FunctionTransformer` without a function is the identity function (`f(x) = x`):

```py
import pandas as pd  # 2.1.4
# import sklearn  # 1.3.2
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer


# Original data.
a = range(1, 10)
b = range(10, 100, 10)
c = range(11, 110, 11)
d = range(12, 120, 12)
e = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii']
f = ['ф', 'и', 'с', 'в', 'у', 'а', 'п', 'р', 'ш']
g = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(']
test = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d, 'e': e, 'f': f, 'g': g}
data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

X = data.drop(columns="f")
y = data.f

drop_cols = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[("identity", FunctionTransformer(), X.columns.drop(labels="g"))],
    remainder="drop",
)
out = drop_cols.fit_transform(X=X)
print(out)
```

```py
[[1 10 11 12 'aa']
 [2 20 22 24 'bb']
 [3 30 33 36 'cc']
 [4 40 44 48 'dd']
 [5 50 55 60 'ee']
 [6 60 66 72 'ff']
 [7 70 77 84 'gg']
 [8 80 88 96 'hh']
 [9 90 99 108 'ii']]
```

This returns an array. If you have `scikit-learn` version `1.2.0` or higher you can have it return a `pandas.DataFrame` instead using the [`set_output`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.set_output) method.

```py
import pandas as pd  # 2.1.4
# import sklearn  # 1.3.2
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer


# Original data.
a = range(1, 10)
b = range(10, 100, 10)
c = range(11, 110, 11)
d = range(12, 120, 12)
e = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii']
f = ['ф', 'и', 'с', 'в', 'у', 'а', 'п', 'р', 'ш']
g = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(']
test = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d, 'e': e, 'f': f, 'g': g}
data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

X = data.drop(columns="f")
y = data.f

drop_cols = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[("identity", FunctionTransformer(), X.columns.drop(labels="g"))],
    remainder="drop",
).set_output(transform="pandas")  # <-- here
out = drop_cols.fit_transform(X=X)
print(out)
```

```py
   identity__a  identity__b  identity__c  identity__d identity__e
0            1           10           11           12          aa
1            2           20           22           24          bb
2            3           30           33           36          cc
3            4           40           44           48          dd
4            5           50           55           60          ee
5            6           60           66           72          ff
6            7           70           77           84          gg
7            8           80           88           96          hh
8            9           90           99          108          ii
```

To keep the original feature names you can set `verbose_feature_names_out=False` in `ColumnTransformer`:

```py
import pandas as pd  # 2.1.4
# import sklearn  # 1.3.2
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer


# Original data.
a = range(1, 10)
b = range(10, 100, 10)
c = range(11, 110, 11)
d = range(12, 120, 12)
e = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii']
f = ['ф', 'и', 'с', 'в', 'у', 'а', 'п', 'р', 'ш']
g = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(']
test = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d, 'e': e, 'f': f, 'g': g}
data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

X = data.drop(columns="f")
y = data.f

drop_cols = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[("identity", FunctionTransformer(), X.columns.drop(labels="g"))],
    remainder="drop",
    verbose_feature_names_out=False,  # <-- here
).set_output(transform="pandas")
out = drop_cols.fit_transform(X=X)
print(out)
```

```py
   a   b   c    d   e
0  1  10  11   12  aa
1  2  20  22   24  bb
2  3  30  33   36  cc
3  4  40  44   48  dd
4  5  50  55   60  ee
5  6  60  66   72  ff
6  7  70  77   84  gg
7  8  80  88   96  hh
8  9  90  99  108  ii
```

### `Pipeline`

The `Pipeline` is probably the easiest part in all this. It runs the provided steps in sequential order. Not much else to it. Most of the work is done with the individual estimators, e.g. `ColumnTransformer`. In your scenario we don't need to drop any columns with the identity function as all columns are assigned  to either `num_clmns` or `cat_clmns`. We drop the remainder.

```py
import pandas as pd  # 2.1.4
# import sklearn  # 1.3.2
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler


# Original data.
a = range(1, 10)
b = range(10, 100, 10)
c = range(11, 110, 11)
d = range(12, 120, 12)
e = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii']
f = ['ф', 'и', 'с', 'в', 'у', 'а', 'п', 'р', 'ш']
g = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(']
test = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d, 'e': e, 'f': f, 'g': g}
data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

X = data.drop(columns="f")
y = data.f
num_clmns = X.select_dtypes(include='int').columns
cat_clmns = X.select_dtypes(include='object').columns

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.3, random_state=42)

trans = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num_trans1', StandardScaler(), num_clmns),
        ('cat_trans1', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_clmns),
    ],
    remainder="drop",
)

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('trans', trans), ('rtc', RandomForestClassifier())])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Because columns `g` and `e` are assigned to `cat_clmns`, we don't actually drop anything. If you really wanted to drop `g`, you'd need to exclude it from `cat_clmns` explicitly.

This is the explicit approach:

```py
import pandas as pd  # 2.1.4
# import sklearn  # 1.3.2
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler


# Original data.
a = range(1, 10)
b = range(10, 100, 10)
c = range(11, 110, 11)
d = range(12, 120, 12)
e = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii']
f = ['ф', 'и', 'с', 'в', 'у', 'а', 'п', 'р', 'ш']
g = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(']
test = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d, 'e': e, 'f': f, 'g': g}
data = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

X = data.drop(columns="f")
y = data.f
num_clmns = X.select_dtypes(include='int').columns
cat_clmns = X.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.drop(labels="g")  # <-- here

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.3, random_state=42)

trans = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num_trans1', StandardScaler(), num_clmns),
        ('cat_trans1', OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_clmns),
    ],
    remainder="drop",
)

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('trans', trans), ('rtc', RandomForestClassifier())])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

---

## Resources

- [`sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html)
- [`sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)
- [Introducing the `set_output` API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_set_output.html)
- [`sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)